# windows phone 7 page transition to itself

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was wondering if it was possible to to a page transition on itself. I wanted the sort of book style flip transition but without actually changing the page it's on (I am updating the page with new information)

I have done searches but I don't think I'm thinking of the right words to search for as I can't find any examples for what I want to do - they're all transitioning to *other* pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christian Schormann demonstrates in [his Mix 2010 talk, CL02](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight-and-windows-phone-7-sessions-from-mix-10) how to animate turning of the current page.

I recommend downloading the high def version so you can have a close look at the steps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was **very** easy to do after watching that video.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Non-Linear Navigation Service](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx)?

Alternatively just update the model the page is bound to and add an animation to simualte the opening of another page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I'm going to write isn't a good practice, but I think it solves.. =P.
You can redirect to a "UtilPage", and inside that UtilPage, you redirect back inside the initialize method or you create a DispatcherTimer to redirect in X mileseconds.

Again, this isn't a good practice, but consering that the framework doesn't help in this case... =p

Answer (score 0):

Take a screen shot of your page with `WriteableBitmap` (like use the UIElement contructor one), put that in `<Image>` control and add it to the grid/canvas. Then update your information. Then animate your `<Image>` any way you like, like a PlaneProjection. Once the storyboard is done, do a `LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(YourImage)`.